# Adding 2008 Server to 2008 Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain-controller

I'm trying to create a lab for testing before I deploy solutions, I'm no experienced IT Administrator, and therefore I come here for help.

I'm running 2 Virtual Servers on the same machine on a local connection between those two. They'are able to ping each other. Their names is TSDATA1 and TSDATA2 where TSDATA1 is the Domain Controller. I am able to ping between those two, on both "ping TSDATA1" and "ping 10.0.0.1" which is the IP address of TSDATA1. The IP address of TSDATA2 is 10.0.0.2.

I'm trying to join the domain with TSDATA2 both I'm getting this error when trying:

> Note: This information is intended for
>   a network administrator.  If you are
>   not your network's administrator,
>   notify the administrator that you
>   received this information, which has
>   been recorded in the file
>   C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.
>
> The following error occurred when DNS
>   was queried for the service location
>   (SRV) resource record used to locate
>   an Active Directory Domain Controller
>   for domain tsdata.local:
>
> The error was: "DNS name does not
>   exist." (error code 0x0000232B
>   RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
>
> The query was for the SRV record for
>   _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.tsdata.local
>
> Common causes of this error include
>   the following:
>
> - The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not
>     registered in DNS. These records are
>     registered with a DNS server
>     automatically when a AD DC is added to
>     a domain. They are updated by the AD
>     DC at set intervals. This computer is
>     configured to use DNS servers with the
>     following IP addresses:
>
> 10.0.0.1
>
> - One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child
>     zone:
>
> tsdata.local local . (the root zone)
>
> For information about correcting this
>   problem, click Help.

I've figured out it has something to do with DNS lookup, but I have no clue what to do.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? How **exactly** did you install the Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stating that it cannot find the SRV record for the domain that you have created.  _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.tsdata.local is the entry that says (esentially) "look here if you need to query for a domain controller"  DNS is the backbone of active directory and if that record is missing there is likely other important bits missing first.

Probably the simplest way to resolve this is to rebuild your domain.  Run dcpromo on your domain controller and remove AD DS.  Once it's removed ensure that DNS is set up properly first by making sure tha you have the tdata.local zone set up properly and both machines register themselves dynamically in that zone.  Once that is done promote tsdata1 back to being a DC (I suspect you will notice the process procede a little faster than before) then try to add tsdata2 to the domain

Comment: I've removed the AD DS, and now there is only DNS on TSDATA1. But under DNS Manager -> Forward/Reverse Lookup Zones, there is nothing? Should I add tsdata.local zone there?

Comment: yes.  DNS must function properly first.  Without a DNS zone to write to AD DS won't tbe able to properly place the records.

Comment: I've now created the zone with the name "tsdata.local" and added a host (A) with the specs: "name: (same as parent folder), type: Host (A), Data: 10.0.0.1" is that correct?

Comment: I made it work now! Thanks alot mate! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the DNS service on the domain controller when you created the domain?

To verify DNS is actually up and running, try doing a `ping tsdata1.tsdata.local` on both servers.

Comment: I could not ping tsdata.tsdata.local on neither of the two servers.

Comment: And yeah, I've installed the DNS Service on the domain controller which I created the Domain is, which is TSDATA1, as the "Main" server, and TSDATA2 as a backup. Im trying to setup DFS, but it requires AD Domain.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with DNS requests being resolved as you are on a .local domain. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/93462/running-a-dns-nameserver-in-a-local-domain) for more details.

If possible, rename the domain to something else (such as tsdata.office). If that isn't possible, then make sure you don't have any multicast dns resolves running on the computers (as they're fresh servers I can't see that you'll have iTunes on them).

Comment: They're newly fresh, I can try to change the name, hence it is only a test system, so there is no requirement for names atm. How do I change the Domain name?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with using a .local domain as it's microsoft DNS

Comment: I dont think either. I think it has something with the setup of DNS, since I'm a total rookie at that field, I have no clue how to set it up properly. Does it normally work "out of the box" on a local closed network?

Comment: If you let dcpromo set it up for you, yes, it normally works "out of the box".

Comment: I've had less than stellar results letting DCpromo set up dns for me.   It's MUCH better under 2k8+ but it's not that much work to manually install the role and set up the zone, compared to the work of troubleshootng why it went wrong.

Comment: I've actually **never** see it go wrong. I have no doubt it *could*... but I'm usually quite confident with it.